# Passing a value for an optional fortran parameter that will return false for present()

Tags: fortran, optional-parameters

I would like to find a way to get a fortran method to take some value for an optional parameter that will make the argument not appear to be present in the method that has been called.

Here is a reduced test case which distills the problem in the fortran code:

```
MODULE FortranOptional
  USE ISO_C_BINDING

CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE optionaltest(scalar)
    REAL(8), OPTIONAL, INTENT(IN) :: scalar

    IF (PRESENT(scalar)) THEN
      print *, "scalar is present: ", scalar
    ELSE
      print *, "scalar is NOT present"
    END IF

  END SUBROUTINE optionaltest

  SUBROUTINE optionaltest_c(scalarC) BIND(C, NAME="optionaltest_c")
    REAL(C_DOUBLE), OPTIONAL, INTENT(IN) :: scalarC
    REAL(8) :: scalar

    IF (PRESENT(scalarC)) THEN
      print *, "scalarC is present: ", scalarC
      scalar = scalarC
    ELSE
      print *, "scalarC is NOT present"
      ! Can I do something here to make scalar appear not present in optionaltest()?
    END IF

    CALL optionaltest(scalar)
  END SUBROUTINE optionaltest_c
END MODULE FortranOptional
```

And the associated C++ test code:

```
extern "C"
{
void optionaltest_c(double*);
}

void testMethod()
{
    double v = 5.3;
    optionaltest_c(0);

    std::cout << "\n";

    optionaltest_c(&v);
}
```

Which produces:

```
scalarC is NOT present
scalar is present:    6.9118029901527309E-310

scalarC is present:    5.2999999999999998     
scalar is present:    5.2999999999999998
```

Is there any way I can set the `scalar` variable based on the presence of `scalarC` that will make it appear to not be present when `scalarC` is not present?

Some constraints:

- I'd prefer to avoid if statements involving different calls to `optionaltest`, as the real version of the subroutine has several optional parameters that may be specified or not on an individual basis, resulting in a combinatorial explosion.
- I cannot bind the `optionaltest` subroutine directly as a C function, as the real version of the subroutine has assumed shape optional arguments, which are not C-compatible in the version of Fortran I am using.
- I cannot modify the signature of `optionaltest`.

Comment: @francescalus: Unfortunately, in the real method, there are computations that must be done in the translation step, so there is no directly analogous variable that I can simply pass-through.

Comment: Perhaps I can explain better: is `CALL optionaltest(scalar)` in subroutine `optionaltest_c` possible, or are you having (perhaps because of different kind/type) that to have `scalar` and `scalarC` distinct variables?

Comment: `CALL optionaltest(scalar)` *does* appear in `optionaltest_c`; did you mean `CALL optionaltest(scalarC)`? I cannot do the latter since, as you guessed, scalar and scalarC are not quite the same and I can't just pass `scalarC` through.

Comment: Yes, I indeed meant `scalarC`.  For interest (or best possible answer), can you state compiler and version?  As you've noted we're in areas of variable support.

Comment: I am using gfortran 4.4.7, and I need to write to the Fortran90 specification.

Comment: I've answered with some parts that may not work with your compiler version, but if you're getting an optional argument in an interoperable procedure to compile that suggests a higher level of support for interop than I'd expect.  Also note that the question's code is well past Fortran 90: at least Fortran 2003.

Comment: *"I need to write to the Fortran90 specification. "* Your code in the question goes actually even beyond Fortran 2008.

Comment: Yes, it does, and I have had subsequent issues related to that. I will leave the answer as accepted, as it does solve the problem for newer versions of Fortran, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the subroutine `optionaltest_c` the variable `scalar` is a local one.  As you note, a local variable has no concept of optional-ness.

For completeness, if it's just a matter of passing the optional dummy argument down from `optionaltest_c` to `optionaltest`, then

```
call optionaltest(scalarC)
```

would suffice.  That is, an optional dummy argument may be an actual argument for a procedure where the corresponding dummy argument is also optional, regardless of its presence.

So, if instead you need to do some form of manipulation, what to do?<sup>1</sup>  I note that you have intrinsic assignment between the dummy argument and local variable.

Under Fortran 2008 there is a sensible option: have the local variable allocatable.  If a variable is not allocated and is an actual argument for an optional non-allocatable dummy then it is treated as not present:

```
  subroutine optionaltest_c(scalarC) bind(C)
    type(type1), optional, intent(in) :: scalarC
    type(type2), allocatable :: scalar  ! Local, conformable with scalarC

    if (PRESENT(scalarC)) scalar=scalarC
    ...

    call optionaltest(scalar)
  end subroutine optionaltest_c
```

[You may need to provide alternative ways of allocating `scalar` and setting its value, depending on your compiler support.]

With `scalarC` present, `scalar` becomes allocated and has its value. Then on the call, the dummy argument is present.  With `scalarC` not present, `scalar` is left not allocated and on the call the dummy argument is absent.

This works just as well for arrays as for scalars.

Now, I see that you mention gfortran 4.4.7, so it's possible this approach won't work.  I'll let someone else answer with a specific way in that case, but this is perhaps still worth documenting for the benefit of others/after upgrade.

---

<sup>1</sup> That may not be the case in this question if `c_double` has value `8`, but we'll consider anyway.

Comment: Making it `allocatable` was what I needed; I was not aware that could be done for scalar variables. Thanks.

Comment: Allocatable scalars (introduced in F2003), even of intrinsic type, are very useful creatures.

Comment: We can pass unallocated allocatable variable to an optional dummy argument? That would likely simplify quite a few places in my code. Unassociated pointer as well?

Comment: (It has been only two years since I realized I can pass an optional dummy as an optional actual argument, line 188 https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/commits/e1bcc50ef16c3c59d58cea682c83329413acb8cf )

Comment: @VladimirF, yes to both unallocated allocatable and disassociated pointer, as long as the dummy isn't allocatable (first) or pointer (second).  See F2008 12.5.2.12.  This it new to F2008 (and very welcome to me) and I've no idea about support in gfortran.